# Facebook API - Check user account creation date

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to check when an account was created with Facebook API?

I would like to allow account creation with Facebook Login only for Facebook users who have a Facebook account for more than one year.

Thank you.

Comment: please accept answer..if it full fill your requirement..

Answer (score 2):

Facebook API doesn't provide the signup date...

You may take a look at  http://metadatascience.com/2013/03/11/inferring-facebook-account-creation-date-from-facebook-user-id/. It explains how to figure out the creation date of a Facebook account without having to call the Facebook API, just based on the user’s Facebook UID.

The [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) lists all the fields you can retrieve using the Graph API.

Comment: This solution was the best, but i think it no longer works, since the introduction of app-scoped user-ids, more info here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Answer (score 1):

Sorry @Psyche

As you want it is not provide by facebook graph API

AND, this data is not available. The best you can do is pull the oldest action taken by the user that is available by the API. Most of the times it is a status post.

hope you can understand my answer.

Comment: http://metadatascience.com/2013/03/14/lookup-table-for-inferring-facebook-account-creation-date-from-facebook-user-id/ also please refer